# Postman - how to get all attribute values and setEnvironment them?

Tags: get, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

In my body return:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "msg": "",
    "data": {
        "events": {
            "1-7396679c-4597-4253-9b8e-f135017c791c": {
                "event": "verbose"
            },
            "2-ee86609a-5c86-4662-a94d-9d4c0e3c836d": {
                "event": "verbose"
            },
            "3-49caf28d-5d68-4606-b487-0284d05ecbc0": {
```

1. How can I setEnvironmentVariable about the first events attribute ("1-7396679c-4597-4253-9b8e-f135017c791c"). I didnt find any information because its always about the value but not the attribute.
2. How, for each attribute events value, setEnvironmentVariable (like a while for all the events attributes)

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: what are your trials and errors?

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code. What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).